# local.Storage redirect if false

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, local-storage

I have a site that needs to verify like a cookie. but i want to use local storage since it is a mobile concept. 
I know the item is set through a test but i cant get the page to redirect when it is not true.

```
<script language="javascript">
 if (localStorage.getItem('itemVerified') = 'True') {
window.location = "success.html";
}
else {
alert("You are not able to enter this site!");
window.location = "error.html";
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have `=` instead of a `==` which is a JS error, so I don't see how this would redirect either way.

Comment: no matter how many times you look at it you never see the obvioous

Answer (score 0):

There may be two errors, the first of which is that your comparison string missing an = sign:

incorrect: `if (localStorage.getItem('itemVerified') = 'True') {`

Correct: `if (localStorage.getItem('itemVerified') == 'True') {`

The second case is if you're looking to check the site from which to load the document you need to add the action to an event listener for them you can do the following.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var verifyCookie = function(){

   if (localStorage.getItem('itemVerified') == 'True') {
    console.log("All right");
        window.location = "success.html";
   }
   else {
    alert("You are not able to enter this site!");
    window.location = "error.html";
   }
      };
     window.addEventListener ('DOMContentLoaded', verifyCookie, false);
    </script>
```

Regards.